# Azure maintenance: possible downtime with 8 instances?

Tags: azure, configuration, cloud

Microsoft just sent out an email notifying our company that there will be scheduled maintenance for our Windows Azure environment.

> We will be performing maintenance on our networking hardware. We are
>   scheduling the update to occur during nonbusiness hours as much as
>   possible, in each maintenance region. Single and multi-instance
>   Virtual Machines and Cloud Services deployments will reboot once
>   during this maintenance operation. **Each instance reboot should last 30
>   to 45 minutes**. 
>   We suggest using **availability sets** in the architecture to protect
>   against downtime caused by planned maintenance. This maintenance will
>   proceed by updating instances in only one Fault Domain (FD) at a time
>   for the Cloud Services and Virtual Machines in an Availability Set.

Now our website consists of **a Cloud Service with 8 (small) instances** of a web role. With these 8 instances, is there still a possibilty of downtime for the website? Do we need to use 'Availability Sets' or are we safe? Thanks for any info..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on which service you're referring to. From my understanding, because you mentioned "Web Role", you're talking about Cloud Services (PaaS).

In General:

1. If you have Cloud Services (PaaS), which is what you have based on my understanding, then you won't have any downtime, no.
2. If you have VMs (Virtual Machines) that don't belong to the same Availability Set, then there is a chance of downtime. To fix that, just make sure they are on the same Availability Set. If you don't have VMs, ignore this.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Panagiotis, thanks for your answer. i am indeed talking about Cloud Services, there are 0 VM's in our environment, so i guess im on the safe side

Comment: You will be fine then :)